# NVL function not returning expression 2

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

in following query, `accoount_num` is `varchar2(20)`, not returning NA. 
999910026A is not there in my table.
I am using oracle database. 
It looks very strange to me.

```
select NVL(account_num,'NA') 
from account 
where account_num='999910026A'
```

Please help me in understanding this.
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does `select * from account where account_num='999910026A' ` gives any result ? There is no account `999910026A` in the table, so the query gives empty resultset.

Comment: If you want exactly 1 result, every time, then do `select nvl(min(account_num), 'NA')`

Comment: you are right, select * from account where account_num='999910026A'  gives no result.

Comment: my requirement is when given account_num is not there in table, it should return NA?
how to achieve this? please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `account_num` field has unique values in the table (maybe even the key?), you can do it by applying an aggregation -- that will always return a result: one result.

```
select nvl(min(account_num),'NA') 
from account 
where account_num='999910026A'
```

Comment: Yes trincot, your suggestion is working...thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

There are no rows in the table with `account_num='999910026A'`, so no rows are returned, and there's nothing to apply `nvl` on.
One way to emulate this behavior is with a `left join`:

```
SELECT    NVL(account_num, 'NA') 
FROM      (SELECT '999910026A' AS literal
           FROM   dual) l
LEFT JOIN account ON account_num = literal
```